# Adsense Ads Not Loading on Joomla Logged In Pages

Tags: joomla-3.x, google

I run a website which has Adsense ads served on all pages (in the footer for example) and these ads load absolutely fine on all pages of my website. I'm currently building a tool/feature for users and they'll need to be logged in to use it (using Joomla login), however when I test this and log in, Adsense ads aren't being served. Sometimes the containers load/render the space, but no ads load.

I've searched high/low for a solution but can't find any help on this issue.

I've tested Adsense code in several different formats, hardcoded, as a module, reusing known good code from other areas of the site. I've also tried creating a standard text based article for logged in users and Adsense ads won't show here either.

Adsense is showing an issue in policy centre, saying I have restricted ad serving on logged in pages but their help centre is next to useless, I've checked everything they suggest but nothing is working. I have set up crawler logins, no blocking in place, Adsense account is verified and been live for years.

There are a handful of error in devtools console, but these are present on pages where Adsense ads display as expected.

Any thoughts or input would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi Dave and welcome to JSE.  Please register your account and take our [tour] to help you to settle into the community.